# A* pathfinding algo for a single layer made from json file iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, algorithm, path-finding

I am trying to implement A* pathfinding algo. M new to iphone development and especially game side. Wanted to ask, I have a tiled map array m reading from a json file. Got all the values of the tiled map in an NSArray. Now i want to implement A* pathfinding algo on it. Do I have to create the A* pathfinding algo with input as NSArray myself or do we have any tutorial of it also. I have tried internet but got tutorials involving tmx files. Can anyone post me some nice tutorials or a sample code or atleast direct me in the right direction. It will be really nice of you guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A* is an algorithm that is at its core applied to a graph. In your case, every node on the graph corresponds to a single tile in your map.

Every edge on the graph corresponds to a an *adjacency* between two tiles.

Implementing A* isn't hard, but it may be overkill for your use. You need to worry about using a priority queue, supporting heuristics, etc.

In your case, a simple [breadth-first-search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) might do the trick as long as there are no weights on your edges.

Rough algorithm sketch:

```
ShortestPath(start, goal):
    let queue = new Queue
    queue.Enqueue(start)
    while (queue is not empty):
        let node = queue.Dequeue()
        if (node == goal) 
            break;
        else
            for each adjacent node, aNode:
                // only add unvisited nodes
                if (aNode.previous == null)
                    aNode.previous = node
                    queue.Enqueue(previous)

    if (node != goal) return failure // we never found the goal, so there's no path

    // trace back your path into a list structure        
    let path = new List

    while (node != null):
        path.Add(node)
        node = node.previous

    // it's in a backwards order, so reverse it
    return path.Reverse()
```